# what would happen if you got a full package of wet silica gel on your hand after it tore open?

Tags: biochemistry, water, safety, materials, chemical-biology

I accidently opened a bag of silica gel and got it on my hand what will happen to my hand because now it kinda feels weird.

Comment: Does your hand feel dry?

Comment: Welcome to chemistry.SE! Had you any questions about the site polices, visit [the help center](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help) or take a [tour](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) of the site.

Comment: Wash your hands real well. Silica shouldn't be harmful unless you're exposed for a long time, or eat it, or breath it somehow.

Answer (score 6):

Like user137 has already written in the comment section it should not be harmful unless exposed for a long time. The main charateristic is its hygroscopy, so skin may feel dry.

To cite from a safety data sheet ([source](http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/MSDS/MSDS/DisplayMSDSPage.do?country=DE&language=EN-generic&productNumber=391484&brand=SIAL&PageToGoToURL=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sigmaaldrich.com%2Fcatalog%2Fproduct%2Fsial%2F391484%3Flang%3Dde)):

```
4 FIRST AID MEASURES
4.1 Description of first aid measures
If inhaled
    If breathed in, move person into fresh air. If not breathing, give artificial respiration.
In case of skin contact
    Wash off with soap and plenty of water.
In case of eye contact
    Flush eyes with water as a precaution.
If swallowed
    Never give anything by mouth to an unconscious person. Rinse mouth with water.
```

Nevertheless: Always use the safety data sheets your distributor provided and read them before dealing with the chemicals, if the safety hazards are not clear.